# rails. select records with max()

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table like this, and I want to return the top two person (by name) with the highest salary, and also the record with the corresponding salary. Here is the table

```
id, name, salary
1, Tom, 200
2, Tom, 300
3, Bob, 400
4, Bob, 500
5, Alice, 600
6, Alice, 700
```

I used this command

```
Employer.select("employers.*, max(employers.salary) as maxsalary").group("employers.name").order("maxsalary desc").limit(2)
```

Desired return:

```
id, name, salary
6, Alice, 700
4, Bob, 500
```

What I got seems to be like this:

```
id, name, salary
5, Alice, 600
3, Bob, 400
```

Is there anyway to select the records responding to the max ? Any comment/answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This Question is very tricky actually!
It seems very easy but it's not.

The Query:

```
Employer.joins(%Q|
  LEFT JOIN employers as e 
  ON 
  e.name = employers.name 
  AND 
  employers.salary < e.salary
|).where('e.salary IS NULL').order('employers.salary DESC').limit(2)
```

**HOW DOES THAT WORK!** (I've been there)

We want to make sure that we only have the highest salary for each employer and then get the highest 2 of those.

---

**Some Theoretical Stuff** (skip this part if you only want to understand the query)

Let Salary be a function S(name,id) where it returns a value given the name and id
To prove that the given salary (S(name,id)) is the highest we have to prove that
We want to prove either

- ∀x S(name,id) > S(name,x) (this salary is higher than all other
  salaries for that name)

OR

- ¬∃x S(name, id) < S(name, x)   (there exists no higher salary for
  that name)

The first approach will need us to get all the records for that name which I do not really like.

The second one will need a smart way to say there can be no record higher than this one.

---

**Back to SQL**

If we left joins the table on the name and salary being less than the joined table:

```
%Q|
      LEFT JOIN employers as e 
      ON 
      e.name = employers.name 
      AND 
      employers.salary < e.salary
    |
```

we make sure that all records that has another record with higher salary for the same user to be joined:

```
employers.id, employers.name, employers.salary, e.id, e.name, e.salary
1           , Tom           , 200             , 2   , Tom   , 300
2           , Tom           , 300
3           , Bob           , 400             , 4   , Bob   , 500
4           , Bob           , 500
5           , Alice         , 600             , 6   , Alice   , 700
6           , Alice         , 700
```

That will help us filter for the highest salary for each employer with no grouping needed:

```
where('e.salary IS NULL')

employers.id, employers.name, employers.salary, e.id, e.name, e.salary
2           , Tom           , 300
4           , Bob           , 500
6           , Alice         , 700
```

Now all we need to do is sort:

```
order('employers.salary DESC')

employers.id, employers.name, employers.salary, e.id, e.name, e.salary
6           , Alice         , 700
4           , Bob           , 500
2           , Tom           , 300
```

Then limit

```
limit(2)

employers.id, employers.name, employers.salary, e.id, e.name, e.salary
6           , Alice         , 700
4           , Bob           , 500
```

And that's the answer we need.

---

**Why don't we**

1.

```
Employer.order('salary desc').limit(2)
```

Because this will get us the records with the highest salaries independent of the name

```
employers.id, employers.name, employers.salary
5           , Alice         , 600
6           , Alice         , 700
```

2.

```
Employer.select('DISTINCT(name)').order('salary desc').limit(2)
```

The problem with that is it will only keep the first appearance of the name then sort

```
employers.id, employers.name, employers.salary
1           , Tom           , 200
3           , Bob           , 400
5           , Alice         , 600
```