# Newest record when multiple found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these `project` records:

```
---------------------------------
|id|name      |rate  |start_date|
---------------------------------
|1 |project A |90.0  |01-01-2017|
|2 |project B |100.0 |01-01-2018|
|3 |project A |95.0  |01-01-2018|
---------------------------------
```

I want all records, except when there are multiple records with the same name, in which case I only want the one with the most recent `start_date`. In the example above, I want to get records 2 and 3.

How can I do that? So far I tried with `distinct`, but without success.

Comment: Tried `distinct` with `order(start_date: :desc)`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
Project.all.group([:name, :id]).select("id, name, max(start_date)")
```

But if the projects are indeed the same, you might want to rethink the design. What is the reason for the duplication of records?

Comment: The reason for this is that a project might get a new rate (I updated the table above) and I need the most actual rate to calculate turnovers.

Comment: In that case, you can better add a flag that indicates that the rate is no longer valid. Or even better, create separate ProjectRate model, that holds the rates for the associated Projects.

Comment: Hmm, a flag sounds good, might do that to make this query easier.

Comment: But please consider creating a separate model for this. Makes your life a lot easier. It even allows you to do per project calculations about changes in rates, average rates etc. A lot more fun!

Answer (score 0):

The Query:

```
SELECT project.*
FROM project
LEFT JOIN project as p 
ON 
  p.name = project.name 
  AND 
  project.start_date < p.start_date
WHERE p.start_date IS NULL
```

**HOW DOES THAT WORK!** (I've been there)

You can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/49466938#49466938) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790274/rails-select-records-with-max/26793285#26793285) to understand how it works.

**Wait but how to do it in rails ?!**

```
Project.joins(%Q|
  LEFT JOIN projects as p 
  ON 
  p.name = projects.name 
  AND 
  projects.start_date < p.start_date
|).where(p: { start_date: nil })
```